# Is there a name for "this" in Java?

Tags: java, this, instance, variable-assignment, field

Eclipse will give an error, "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable", when I try something like:

```
public class Thing{

  String a1;
  int a2;

  public void meth(){
    Thing A = new Thing();
    this = A;
  }
}
```

I had to assign each variable (`this.a1 = A.a1; this.a2 = A.a2;`) as a work around.

Are there other ways to do this without going through each variable field?
And if `this` is not a variable what is it called?

Comment: Don't just down vote, explain why this doesn't make sense.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: The name for 'this' is 'this'. Not a real question.

Comment: Why are people upvoting "I didn't do any research at all" ?

Comment: From your assignment block, the use of `this` is meaningless.  There's no ambiguity in the variables you're assigning.

Comment: @EJP then you need to read more than just the title. The title itself, admittably, is incorrect.

Comment: @JanDvorak The question in the title is not a real question. The title is not only incorrect, it is also both meaningless and irrelevant. The imputation that I haven't read further is false.

Comment: @BrianRoach if the guy doesn't understand OOP enough to know why the question doesn't make sense, he could probably use an explanation of what `this` means rather than just downvote, downvote, close. We were all beginners once...

Comment: @Oliver - Which is why I linked to the excellent tutorial provided by Oracle on the subject which is at the top of the list if you google "java this tutorial". The number one reason to downvote is *no research effort*. I'm also out of votes from last night, so I don't have a dog in that race.

Comment: @Oliver the point Brian makes is that the asker shows no research, not that he does not know the basics.

Comment: @Oliver I am agree with you. So many people ask question are nubiee, but we should help them not discourage them.

Comment: Essentially what you're work around is trying to do is set your instance variables to null, based on what you've put in your code, as the new Thing has no instantiation of it's variables. I can't imagine what you're trying to accomplish here that would require a second instance of Thing.

Comment: The only language I'm aware of that lets you reassign "this" is Objective-C (where the roughly identical concept is called "self").  C++ has object-to-object assignment, but that's not the same thing.  The difference is that in Objective-C you're changing the pointer, while with C++ you're changing the object addressed by the pointer.

Comment: The this tag also answers the second part of the question, amusingly.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`this` is a *pseudo-variable* that points to the current instance of the object, it can not be reassigned. It's also considered a keyword in the language, according to section [§3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).

Comment: "Pseudovariable" is a very good term for it. It's in almost every object-oriented C-style language (C++, Java, C#) and has parallels in all the other O/O langs (VB "Me", Obj-C "self", Delphi "Self"), all of which have practically the same usage and restrictions.

Comment: its not a "pseudo-variable", it is a `keyword` that is treated like an `expression` s/a (1 + 2).  And (1 + 2) = A does not make sense.  See my answer below

Comment: It is an immutable reference value.

Answer (score 24):

No, there is no easy shortcut.

> And if "this" is not a variable what is it called?

`this` is not a variable, it's a [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

Even though `this` is special, in many respects it acts like a reference. Therefore, for consistency, `this = A` would have to be a reference assignment, which doesn't quite make sense.

You seem to be expecting `this = A` to perform a field-by-field copy from `A` to `this`, and indeed Java's designers could choose do that in this case. However, this would be inconsistent with other reference assignments, and the overall benefits of having this as an exception are not at all clear.

Comment: The explanation you give is plain wrong: Other languages allow such style of assignment just fine and either infer which field assignments are necessary or let the programmer provide this information. Java’s refusal to allow the assignment has got nothing to do with fields. I’m surprised by the number of upvotes this has garnered.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Many other languages permit many other things. The question is specifically about Java, and Java's design is rather strict in many respects. This is one facet of that.

Comment: @NPE I am objecting specifically to this: “Only you, the programmer, know how the assignment should work” – regardless of language this is not a reason to forbid this assignment. This is true for Java as well, I just mentioned other languages because they *show* that this reason is wrong. The real reason is completely different (assignment on reference objects in Java assigns references, not values, and `this` cannot be assigned to). Your explanation is plausible, but simply wrong and doesn’t apply.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You're reading it differently than what was intended. I'll see if I can improve the wording.

Answer (score 9):

`this` refers to `this` instance of the class.

You cannot assign to `this`

Answer (score 9):

[**this**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) is a java reserved keyword which refers to the current object. its not a variable its a java reserved keyword. 
so `this = A;` is invalid. using `this` keyword we can refer to any instance variable or method of the current object. you have to refer to the instance variable like:

```
this.a1 = A.a1;
```

**From Doc**:

> The most common reason for using the this keyword is because a field
>   is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign to `this` in Java.  It's not a variable; it's a keyword.

One thing you might consider, if you don't need a particular instance, is just `return`ing your new instance.

```
public class Thing{

  String a1;
  int a2;

  public Thing meth(){
    Thing A = new Thing();
    return A;
  }
}
```

and you'd use it like

```
whatever = whatever.meth();
```

Comment: You also can't assign to `final` variables outside of where it is initialized (for local variables) or the constructor (for instance variables)

Comment: "this" is a keyword, but it can be considered to be a variable as well - it "varies" based on the context (even if it is not variable [<- adjective] in the sense that it can be changed by the user).

Comment: @simon: Someone else actually called it a "pseudo-variable", which seems almost fitting.  I couldn't consider it a variable, though; a variable (even a `final` one) has a place where its value is stored, and as far as i can tell, there's really no such place for `this`.

Comment: In compiled bytecode, `this` is the first parameter of a method call (much like Python's `self`), so it really does have a location. In fact, it works very much like a final parameter.

Answer (score 5):

According to [java lang spec §15.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3) `this` is a **keyword** that is either an **expression** or **statement**

1. When used as a **primary expression** `this` denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked.

   - **Expression:** Something which evaluates to a value. Example: *x++*
2. The keyword this is also used in a special explicit constructor invocation **statement**

   - **Statement:** Syntactic elements that control the execution of a program, which are executed for their effect and do not have values Example: *if (true)*

In either case it is not a **variable**

- **Variable:** A storage location with an associated type

In your case `this` is an **expression** and not a **variable**.  But for all intents an purposes just call it a **keyword**

- **Keyword:** A character sequence, formed from ASCII letters, are reserved for use ... that cannot be used as a variable name

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the owner of the method.
In this case, the owner is the object itself.

Sometime, `this` may not refer to the class that you are writing code. Such as in the annoymous class. A common example is the anonymous listener.

```
 button.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                this; // refers to the ActionListener
            }
        }
    );
```

In addition, you can return `this` can do `method chaining`. Supposed you have a class called Homework and it has a method addTask.

```
public Homework addTask(String task){
return this;
}
```

you can call the **addTask** method like

```
homework.addTask("a").addTask("b").addTask("c");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is asking for the ability to assign the contents of one object to another, rather than to assign a new value to the "this" pointer.  C++ has this ability -- you can override the assignment operator -- but Java has no such ability.

It would be a nice feature to have in some occasional cases, but it's simply not currently possible, and it doesn't really fit the Java "mold" to provide the function in the future.

The capability would be more useful (and there would be more motivation to provide it) if Java allowed objects to be embedded in other objects (vs simply embedding referenced), but that's not in the cards either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no<sup>1</sup> way to copy the values of all fields from one instance onto another in the basic Java language. And you should typically not need it. You can most often just replace the reference to the new instance or work directly on the target instance.

In your case when you want to reset all fields of a object to the initial values (and there is seldomly a need for it) you typically use a reset method which eighter works on its own instance or is a static one working on any given object.

So

```
class A {
  String a1; int a2;
  void reset() { a1 = ""; a2 = 0; }
}
```

would be used as

```
A a = new A();
// modify a
a.reset();
```

and

```
class A {
  String a1; int a2;
  static void reset(A anotherA) { anotherA.a1 = ""; anotherA.a2 = 0; }
}
```

and use it like:

```
A.reset(a);
```

In both cases it makes sense to use the reset method also for setting the initial values in the constructor: `A() { A.reset(this); }` or `A() { this.reset(); }`

<sup>1</sup> actually there are some libraries to do it, and you can code it with the help of reflection, the only reason I see it is used is to implement a clone() method or for some kind of wrapping/stubbing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you're trying to do is have a method that reinitializes your object, i.e., set's it back to it's initial values. That's why you want to create a new object, and assign it to the current object, right?

If that's the case, let's try a different way of doing it, since, as has been said, you can't reassign `this`.

What if, instead of doing that, you tried something like this:

```
public class Thing {

    String a1;
    int a2;

    public Thing() {
        this.meth();
    }

    public void meth() {
        this.a1 = "a1";
        this.a2 = 2;
    }

}
```

This way, Thing.meth() actually initializes your object, and the constructor calls it when the object is created. Then you can call it again whenever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

==Disclaimer, I don't know java==

You would want to assign manually.

I'm not sure why you are trying to create a new instance of Thing inside Thing, but as you don't set the values of a1 and a2 you would need to assign them the way you did.

this is a reserved keyword pointing the class object it is inside.

For example, if you wanted to have another function named fish() your code may look something like this.

```
public class Thing{

  String a1;
  int a2;

  public Thing meth(){
    Thing A = new Thing();
    return A;
  }

  public Thing fish(){
    this.a1 = "foo";
    this.meth();
    return A;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `this = stuff;` you are trying to replace the **current** object instance reference (in this case, the one that you are initializing in the constructor) with another thing, and (in the particular case of java) thats illegal and the language forbids you of doing it.

Think about it, if you could replace the reference to your current instance just like that, then you could incur in some serious memory and security problems (the reference to the constructed object will be lost and overrided by some unknown object).

What is totally valid is referencing members of your **current** object using the `.` operator, because they are owned by `this`, so no problems should arise (at least not evident ones).

The JVM has some inner security measures (e.g., method max stack size verification, class file format validation, etc) that prevents from easy binary manipulation and are enforced by the language syntax. This could be seen as one of those.