# What does "this" do in Java?

Tags: java, this

k, I am going through few Game Development Tutorials of Java, and I have to work with Threads and there is a "this" thing
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
that I am unable to understand, I am implementing my Class by "Runnable". What I think about it, is that "this" refers to Runnable to seek for the Run Method that I have defined in MY Class. And If I don't do this, It won't be looking for Run() Method here in my Class. Don't really know If M-Effed, but please correct me If I am wrong....

Comment: Please, please, please find a book on basic object-oriented programming and read it.

Comment: But I really don't understand. Here there are a lot of people who start difficult real application without any java(or other PL) knowledge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a [pseudo-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848176/is-there-a-name-for-this-in-java/13848203#13848203) that points to the current instance, to the object itself where the method is being executed. So for example:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    public void setName(pName) {
        this.name = pName
    }
}

Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Peter");
```

In the above code, we're assigning the new `name` `"Peter"`to *this* person `p`, the current instance of the class `Person`. In other words, from the point of view of `p`, `this` is pointing to `p`.

Answer (score 0):

@Óscar López explains what `this` means.

If your code contains this:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
```

then `this` refers to an instance of the class that contains that statement.  Furthermore, it is *the* instance that is running the code.  Furthermore, the API spec of that `Thread` constructors means that `this` needs to be an instance of a class that implements `Runnable`.

In short, your class needs to be declared as `implements Runnable`, and it needs to have a method with this signature:

```
    public void run()
```